# Upload to iCloud Photos without adding to Recents album?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, photos, album

I'm trying to upload my photo album from my Hard Disk to iCloud, and make it accessible from my iPhone.

However, all the photos uploaded to an album are automatically added to my "Recents" album on my iPhone (in addition to the album itself).

I would like to use iCloud as a cloud storage service and be able to see the photos from my iPhone but without having them in "Recents" album.

- **macOS version**: Catalina
- **iOS version**: 13.1.2

Can this "Recents" album be suppressed / disabled or otherwise made not so prominent?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the `Recents` album does show imported photos first, regardless of when those photos were originally taken. I'm always slightly annoyed by this when I import an older SD Card from my camera.

Try to ignore the `Recents` album.

Instead, use the `Photos` tab section in the main view. **These photos are arranged by date.**

In iOS 13, they are given a nice Years / Months / Days view to quickly zoom in to times and events.

[image]